# Adding second item to listview overrides the first one

Tags: android, listview

I have one activity with an empty ListView and a button for the user to create new items(in a second activity). The first item is created and added to the ListView correectly but the second item overrides the first one or it dissapears somewhere. Below is my code

```
public class Series extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

ListView seriesView;
Button btnNewSerie;
String titleNew = "";
Integer seasonNew = 1;
Integer seasonLengthNew = 23;
private ArrayList<SerieModel> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_series);

    seriesView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.seriesView);
    btnNewSerie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddSerie);
    btnNewSerie.setOnClickListener(this);
    list = new ArrayList<>();

    MyArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, list);
    seriesView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
    // click and edit a serie
    seriesView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intentEdit = new Intent(Series.this, EditSerie.class);
            String title = (String) seriesView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            intentEdit.putExtra("Title", title);
            // TODO: 01/10/15 Add season and last chapter as extras
            startActivity(intentEdit);
        }
    });

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        titleNew = extras.getString("Title");
        seasonNew = extras.getInt("Season");
        seasonLengthNew = extras.getInt("Duration");

        SerieModel addedSerie = new SerieModel(titleNew, seasonNew, seasonLengthNew);
        list.add(addedSerie);
        myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}

public void setListData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        final SerieModel tempSerie = new SerieModel(titleNew, seasonNew, seasonLengthNew);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post your second activity

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: because the new item is created in another activity, the items stored in 'list' are destroyed when OnPause is called (forgot about Activity lifecycle). My solution is to store items in a SQLite database, following [this tutorial](http://vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).